# Problem with for loop and localstorage in javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have this code and it is functional, but the only problem is that it does not save me the localstorage as I really want. The loop keeps all the keys but with the same last value:

```
"use strict";

var form = document.querySelector("#form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
  var name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
  var year = document.querySelector("#year").value;
  var productor = document.querySelector("#productor").value;
  var director = document.querySelector("#director").value;

  if (name === "" || year == "" || productor == "" || director == "") {
  } else {
    let body = document.querySelector("tbody");
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    body.appendChild(tr);

    var datos = [name, year, productor, director];
    var keys = ["name", "year", "productor", "director"];
    for (var k in keys) {
      for (var d in datos) {
        localStorage.setItem(keys[k], datos[d]);
      }
    }


    for (let d in datos) {
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      tr.appendChild(td);
      var text = document.createTextNode(datos[d]);
      td.appendChild(text);
    }
  }
});

var clear = document.querySelector("#clear");
```

the problem I suppose is right here:

```
for (var k in keys) {
      for (var d in datos) {
        localStorage.setItem(keys[k], datos[d]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: You are overwriting the value of the key with each iteration of your inner loop (and ending up with just the last value). What result are you trying to get?

Comment: @benvc For each element of the "key" array I want to obtain the value of each of the elements of the "data" array.

Comment: You'd be better bulding a nice object (a single one), and to store its JSON stringification. Having a lot of Storage keys is always a mess (what if a plugin also uses name as a key?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment, you are overwriting the value of each key with each iteration of your inner loop (and setting them all to the last value in your `datos` array). I think you are looking to set each key in your `keys` array to a value corresponding to the item at the same index in your `datos` array. For example:

```
const datos = ['Working Title', '2018', 'Patty Producer', 'Danny  Director'];
const keys = ['name', 'year', 'productor', 'director'];
keys.forEach((k, i) => {
  localStorage.setItem(k, datos[i]);
});
    
console.log(localStorage.getItem('name')); // Working Title
```

Comment: Thank you, that's working for me. I'm understand now